# Expedited WorkRequests require a ListenableWorker to provide an implementation for getForegroundInfoAsync()

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

Doing a little [Jeopardy style Q&A](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) here.

I have some work I sometimes need to run as *expedited* as described in the [version 2.7.0 of `WorkManager`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.7.0):

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()
val oneTimeWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker::class.java)
    .setInitialDelay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)
    .setConstraints(constraints).build()
WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniqueWork("my-identifier", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, oneTimeWorkRequest)
```

I believe the code ran just fine on Android 12/S, but when the job is run on Android 11 I get the following error:

```
E/WM-WorkerWrapper: Work [ id=<UUID>, tags={ [WorkerTag] } ] failed because it threw an exception/error
     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expedited WorkRequests require a ListenableWorker to provide an implementation for `getForegroundInfoAsync()`
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:516)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:475)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:311)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The documentation for `ListenableWorker.getForegroundInfoAsync()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#getForegroundInfoAsync()) states this:

> Prior to Android S, WorkManager manages and runs a foreground service on your behalf to execute the WorkRequest, showing the notification provided in the ForegroundInfo. To update this notification subsequently, the application can use NotificationManager.
>
> Starting in Android S and above, WorkManager manages this WorkRequest using an immediate job.

So in the class extending `ListenableWorker` it's necessary to override `getForegroundInfoAsync()`.

An alternative to directly overriding that method yourself is to use for example [`CoroutineWorker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/CoroutineWorker):

```
    class MyWorker(val context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {

    companion object {
        private const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "11"
        private const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "Work Service"
    }

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        // TODO: Do work here
        return Result.success()
    }

    override suspend fun getForegroundInfo(): ForegroundInfo {
        val notificationManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java), Constants.PENDING_INTENT_FLAG_IMMUTABLE))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_refresh_24dp)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setLocalOnly(true)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_SECRET)
            .setContentText("Updating widget")
            .build()
        return ForegroundInfo(1337, notification)
    }

}
```

(That constant for the pending intent flag is really just `val PENDING_INTENT_FLAG_MUTABLE = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE else 0` to make stuff work with both Android 12/S and earlier.)

Comment: On the other words, using Expedited work for sdk >= android12, you don't need to modify any code. But for sdk <12, since WorkManager handle this in foreground service, you need to provide notification.

Comment: @RoySolberg can you please see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70610967/11560810)

Comment: Thanks @prokash-sarkar !
I have two additions: 

1. The whole block could be put into an IF to do the notification thing only up to Android 11: 
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) { /* BLOCK ABOVE */ } else { return super.getForegroundInfo() } 
2. The Priority of the notification is set to PRIORITY_MIN, but the notification channel is set to NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH. If you don't want the notification to appear (like in my case), you should also set the importance to NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN

Answer (score 0):

If you have written your ListenableWorker in Java, the solution looks like this:

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@NonNull
@Override
public ListenableFuture<ForegroundInfo> getForegroundInfoAsync() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        return super.getForegroundInfoAsync();
    } else {
        final SettableFuture<ForegroundInfo> notificationFuture = SettableFuture.create();
        final ForegroundInfo notification = mUploadNotificationBuilder.build(getApplicationContext());
        notificationFuture.set(notification);

        return notificationFuture;
    }
}
```