# Upgrading to WorkManager 2.7.0: How to implement getForegroundInfoAsync for RxWorker?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

My app is targeting API 31/Android 12 and version 2.7.0 of WorkManager is required for that according to [Google](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#version_27_2), so in order to do that, I have added `setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)` to my `OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder` and added the necessary changes in the AndroidManifest as well (see this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.6.0) for details). However, when I ran my app I encountered this error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expedited WorkRequests require a ListenableWorker to provide an implementation for `getForegroundInfoAsync()`
```

There are no examples or documentation provided by Google on how to do this for RxWorker, but I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69627330/expedited-workrequests-require-a-listenableworker-to-provide-an-implementation-f) here in Stackoverflow, but it is for Coroutines.

My question is how do you implement the said `getForegroundInfoAsync` for `RxWorker` when `getForegroundInfoAsync` has to return `ListenableFuture<ForegroundInfo>`--reading the docs it seems I have to add Guava to my app to do this? Since the docs for `ListenableFuture` says to `Avoid implementing ListenableFuture from scratch. If you can't get by with the standard implementations, prefer to derive a new Future instance with the methods in Futures or, if necessary, to extend AbstractFuture.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: Currently, there are two ways to approach this:

**1. Using restricted API**

Looking at the source code for `ListenableWorker`, we find this for `getForegroundInfoAsync`:

```
    @NonNull
    public ListenableFuture<ForegroundInfo> getForegroundInfoAsync() {
        SettableFuture<ForegroundInfo> future = SettableFuture.create();
        String message =
                "Expedited WorkRequests require a ListenableWorker to provide an implementation for"
                        + " `getForegroundInfoAsync()`";
        future.setException(new IllegalStateException(message));
        return future;
    }
```

So in my own RxWorker's implementation of getForegroundInfoAsync, I tried creating a `SettableFuture` but I saw a lint warning telling me that usage of `SettableFuture` is restricted within its library. But this can be bypassed by just annotating the implementation `getForegroundInfoAsync` with `@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")`. Here is how my code roughly looks like:

```
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun getForegroundInfoAsync(): ListenableFuture<ForegroundInfo> {
        val future = SettableFuture.create<ForegroundInfo>()

        val notificationId = id.hashCode()
        val fileName = inputData.getString(KEY_OUTPUT_FILE_NAME)

        if (fileName == null) {
            future.setException(IllegalStateException("Filename is null"))
            return future
        }

        val notificationBuilder = getNotificationBuilder(fileName)

        future.set(ForegroundInfo(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build()))
        return future
    }
```

**2. Using CallbackToFutureAdapter**

Instead of relying on restricted API, you can use `CallbackToFutureAdapter`, but this solution requires the Futures AndroidX library, see link [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/concurrent). After adding the said library to your project, you can use `CallbackToFutureAdapter` to return a ListenableFuture in this way:

```
override fun getForegroundInfoAsync(): ListenableFuture<ForegroundInfo> {
    val fileName = inputData.getString(KEY_OUTPUT_FILE_NAME)

    return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture {
        if (fileName == null) {
            it.setException(IllegalStateException("Filename is null"))
        } else {
            notificationBuilder = getNotificationBuilder(fileName)

            it.set(ForegroundInfo(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build()))
        }
    }
}
```

One warning though, when creating a `PendingIntent` for your Notification, do not forget to have `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` flag set (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69627330/expedited-workrequests-require-a-listenableworker-to-provide-an-implementation-f) for details)

Comment: Dear friends, any soultion for Java?

Comment: Hi @BobTheCat, take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/concurrent/futures/CallbackToFutureAdapter for Java examples for CallbackToFutureAdapter

Comment: Any way to update the notification to show the progress of the worker by using this approach?

Answer (score 7):

Another way to do this that doesn't require a restricted API or importing the futures library is to use the `Futures.immediateFuture()` method:

```
override fun getForegroundInfoAsync(): ListenableFuture<ForegroundInfo> {
    val notificationId = // some int id for your notification
    val notification = // build your notification in the normal way
    return Futures.immediateFuture(ForegroundInfo(notificationId, notification))
}
```

Comment: Any way to update the notification to show the progress of the worker?